# Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager.GetEnumerator() what does it return?

Tags: powershell, user-profile

I know it returns an array of user profiles but how do I see what fields are on the profile so that I can maniplaute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a variable and populate it with the ProfileManager.GetEnumerator() and then select the properties you are looking for.

Something like:

```
$profiles = $profilemanager.GetEnumerator()
$profiles | Select DisplayName, JobTitle
```

Answer (score 1):

it returns an IEnumerator that can be used to iterate through all profiles.

It only ever seems to return a capped number of items, 200 apparently, when there are supposed to be over 1,000 user profiles imported from AD